# add a call gate descriptor in Local Descriptor Table (LDT) for privilege escalation

Tags: kernel, privileges, descriptor

Can I use the system call `modify_ldt` to add a new entry (call gate descriptor) in LDT?

- If yes, does it mean I can setup this descriptor with descriptor
  privilege level(DPL) 3 and the code segment equal to `KERNEL_CS` 
  (which is the kernel code descriptor for CPL0) pointing back into the
  process’s address space below `TASK_SIZE` thus allowing an user mode 
  task to directly call its own code at CPL0.
- If no, why not?

I am a beginner in this field. Many thanks for your patience and effort.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the system call `modify_ldt` to add a new entry (call gate descriptor) in LDT?

No, you cannot add a call gate using this system call, since it is a system descriptor. Looking at [what information can be provided](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/modify_ldt.2.html) to the system call ...

```
struct user_desc {
  unsigned int  entry_number;
  unsigned long base_addr;
  unsigned int  limit;
  unsigned int  seg_32bit:1;
  unsigned int  contents:2; // HERE
  unsigned int  read_exec_only:1;
  unsigned int  limit_in_pages:1;
  unsigned int  seg_not_present:1;
  unsigned int  useable:1;
};
```

... we see that we can only provide two bits in the `contents` field to describe the type of descriptor we'd like to have. Tracking that data through the system call functions in the Linux kernel isn't that straight forward, but I'm pretty sure that this data finally arrives at [`fill_ldt`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h#L11), which contains these lines:

```
// ...
desc->type = (info->read_exec_only ^ 1) << 1;
desc->type |= info->contents << 2;
desc->s = 1;
// ...
```

The [member fields](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/desc_defs.h#L22) `type` and `s` together with fields for the descriptor privilege level (DPL) and the present flag form [byte 5 of the descriptor](http://wiki.osdev.org/Descriptors). The member `s` ends up at bit 4 (well, the "S" bit) which defines whether the descriptor is a system descriptor (`S=0`) or a (code/data) segment (`S=1`). Since the code above hardcodes the value `1`, you always get a (code/data) segment, never a system descriptor. So no call gates.

> [..] for privilege escalation

Thus the answer here is no. Otherwise this would be a huge security flaw in the design of the Linux kernel. I was a bit surprised that the processor would actually allow call gates in the LDT, thus placing the burden on the operating system to detect (or completely disallow) misuse of that feature.